# Survival prediction with messy longitudinal data

Tags: regression, spss, longitudinal-data-analysis

I'm a doctor, and I'm starting to get the feeling that I am rather out of my depth with a project I'm currently working on. I'd appreciate any pointers towards the correct approach, further reading, etc.

I have a data set of around 2000 patients, and I am trying to gain an understanding of how the results of various tests can be used to predict mortality. For similar projects in the past, we've used cox regression, just based on data collected right at the start of the study, which was moderately straightforward. Now, however, I have several covariates which change considerably over time. The data is retrospective, so each patient has these measured at wildly different times (though I do have all the dates for the measurements). Sick patients, i.e. those more likely to reach the mortality end point, will have them measured more frequently. Clinically, I would assume the variables move in a straight line between each point at which they're measured (last value carried forward would probably make less sense from the clinical point of view in this case).

I've been playing with SPSS, but I can't quite work out how to use this rather irregular data as a time-dependent covariate in a cox regression model. Any help or advice would be very gratefully received.